# Redis, Mongoid, Rails - Use redis attributes in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, redis

```
def add_like user_id
  $redis.sadd "likes:#{_id}", user_id
end

def remove_like user_id
  $redis.srem "likes:#{_id}", user_id
end

def likes
  return $redis.scard("likes:#{_id}")
end
```

Very simple code for adding likes. The thing is, I want to retrieve them easily in the controller. e.g. when I do `@event = Event.find(params[:id]` I want to be able to access the likes in the view as `@event.likes`.

Suggestions?

More importantly, I want to check if the current user has liked this. where do I put this code? in the controller? iterate over all the events with `liked_this?` this smells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This is what happens when I type code from memory. For ActiveRecord, `self.id` returns the primary key of the current record, which is an integer unless you intentionally set it to something else. For Mongoid, `self.id` returns a `BSON::ObjectId` instead. You need a string key for Redis, so you must call `to_s` on the BSON object like so: `self.id.to_s`.

Adding the ability to `@event.likes` in your views is trivial. Add the `likes` method to your model like so:

```
def Event
  def likes
    $redis.scard("likes:#{self.id.to_s}") # return is not necessary
  end
end
```

If you want to use mongoid to check if the current user has liked an event without iterating over each event, you'll need to store likes in mongodb rather than redis.

Answer (score 0):

In the model:

```
after_initialize :likes
```

and

```
def likes
  return self['likes'] = $redis.scard("likes:#{_id}")
end
```

I'm not exactly sure why, [this page in the docs helped me](http://mongoid.org/docs/documents/dynamic.html), and I don't like the fact I'm programming this by coincidence/intuition.